# Sending partial view Vs. string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am converting a webforms project to mvc3 and I found a web method which returns a string that represents an html page like: `"<div>test....</div>"`. Later it is assigned to a division in the page using javascript. Now I doubt whether it is same as sending a partial view representing that html code. Or which is the better method?

```
public ActionResult TestMethod()
        {
            return PartialView("TestView");
        }
```

or

```
    public string TestMethod()
            {
                string htmlContent="<div>..</div>";
                return htmlContent;
            }// and then populating a division in the view with this content
```

?

Comment: they are both the same, using a partial will be cleaner and give you more control over the actual html with razor

Comment: I think partial view is better, more conceptual.

Comment: Partial view is s better choice. In this way you keep html where it belongs.

Comment: Partial view are type-safe, allow static syntax and type checking. So, I think partial views are better choice.

Comment: If you need a simple reusable html fragment, an alternative solution is write your own Html Helper.

Comment: String allows cross-site scripting attacks.  The MvcHtml returned by a view, partial or otherwise, is html encoded to prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the PartialView is the correct method as it maintains the separation of concerns between the view and the controller.

This also allows you to pass a model to the controller and utilise Razor for the formatting.